# How to get not a 'hit' when a specific word isn't found in the whole string?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have a few strings:

```
1. "I offer a jacket from adidas"
2. "I offer clothing from adidas, a jacket"
3. "By my adidas jacket"
4. "adidas jacket"
5. "jacket adidas"
6. "I offer some shoes from adidas"
7. "Selling some nice adidas shoes"
8. "I have some shoes from adidas"
```

Now I want a hit, when the word "adidas" is found, but not when somewhere in the string "jacket" is included.

I manage to get a non-hit when the word "jacket" is behind the word "adidas", but I get a hit, when the word "jacket" is in front of "adidas".

```
adidas(?!.*jacket.*)
```

shows hits for 1., 5., 6., 7. and 8.
But 1 and 5 shouldn't be shown as hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the negative lookahead at the start and use an anchor `^` and word boundaries `\b` to prevent the word being part of a larger word.

```
^(?!.*\bjacket\b).*\badidas\b.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bjacket\b)` Assert what is on the right does not contain `jacket`
- `.*\badidas\b.*` Match 0+ times any char, then match `adidas` and 0+ times any char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgFhPa/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped me.